# How is it possible for QuerySet.count() to return non-zero values but for list(QuerySet.all()) to yield an empty list?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I am running a script using django-extensions and here is the paused execution of it.

[image: illustrating the problem]

How is this possible?

I am running Django 2.2.1 on Windows with a local postgres instance. The database itself was restored using `psql` from a dump created with `pg_dump | gzip`. There is another database, which was restored using pgAdmin from a custom format file, on which the code works fine, so I guess I messed up the restoration, but how?

Comment: have you tried to print objects? **`print(objects)`**?

Comment: or, did you check the length of the objects list? **`print(len(objects))`**?

Comment: Both of those print what is expected: `[]` and `0` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got fixed after recreating the backup with options `--format=c --blobs --section=pre-data --section=data --section=post-data`.